# Sort a Vec of structs with String fields by multi keys?

Tags: rust

I'm wondering if there is a faster/better rust code than the following code to sort a struct Vec with String fields by multiple keys?

I have tried with sort_by_key, but it requires refid.clone().

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Gap {
    refid: String,    
    start: u32,       
    end: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut gaps = vec![
        Gap{
            refid: "fakmffafa".to_string(),    
            start: 1,       
            end: 10,
            
        },
        Gap{
            refid: "cajnfjkabfa".to_string(),    
            start: 5,       
            end: 7,
        },
        Gap{
            refid: "cajnfjkabfa".to_string(),    
            start: 2,       
            end: 5,
        },
    ];
    
    gaps.sort_by(|a, b| {
        if a.refid != b.refid {
            a.refid.cmp(&b.refid)
        } else if a.start != b.start {
            a.start.cmp(&b.start)
        }else {
            a.end.cmp(&b.end)
        }
    });
    
    println!("{:?}", gaps);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your if/else chain by using the [`then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then) method on each `Ordering`, which will use the next comparison strategy if the previous one returned `Equal`:

```rust
gaps.sort_by(|a, b| {
    a.refid.cmp(&b.refid) // try to compare by `refid`
        .then(a.start.cmp(&b.start)) // check `start` if `refid`s are equal
        .then(a.end.cmp(&b.end)) // check `end` if `start`s are equal 
});
```

Another method would be to [derive `Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#derivable) on your struct. It will default to a top-to-bottom order based on how you defined your struct:

```rust
// `Ord` checks top-to-bottom `refid`, `start`, then `end`
#[derive(Debug, Default, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct Gap {
    refid: String,
    start: u32,
    end: u32,
}

fn main() {
    // ...
    gaps.sort(); // now you don't have to manage it anymore!
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you don't want to rely on the layout of the struct for the derive implementation but still want to be able to use built-in methods like `sort`, you can write out your own implementation for the `Ord` traits as well:

```rust
impl PartialOrd for Gap {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl Ord for Gap {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.refid.cmp(&other.refid)
            .then(self.start.cmp(&other.start))
            .then(self.end.cmp(&other.end))
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to manually implement `Ord`, so that it doesn't change when you change the layout of the struct.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good suggestion, it gives more control and still abstracts the comparison logic away

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze unless its `#[repr(C)]`, the "layout" of the struct is entirely a user convenience.

Comment: @Masklinn But it will change if you add, or remove fields.

Comment: Which is usually what you want.

Comment: Prefer `then_with()` to `then()`.